# Is it possible to get in to Genetic Engineering after completing a bachelors in computer science?

Tags: graduate-admissions, career-path, computer-science

I am almost done with my bachelors in Computer Science. After BS(CS), I am interested in Nanotechnology/Nano-electronics and Genetic Engineering. I would prefer Nanotechnology/Nano-electronics first and then Genetic Engineering. My goal is not a good salary, I am very fairly skilled in Computer Science so that's enough for financial support. I want to study these subjects because I like them. So my question is that is it possible to get an admission for either of these courses after a bachelors in Computer Science?

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE. This site neither aspires nor is it equipped to be a database for admission criteria. You have to look into the criteria for your desired programs or ask the respective admission offices. See also [this Meta post](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/q/3406/7734).

Comment: Why does _very fairly skilled in Computer Science_ have anything to do with _that's enough for financial support_?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: This seems to be an acceptable question. While I do agree with you, your comment itself entails an answer that could be helpful for the OP.

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac: *your comment itself entails an answer that could be helpful for the OP.* – Sure, but then that’s the entire point of the close reason in question: We got tired of answering questions with little more than: “consult the programme’s guidelines or admission office”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is common for graduates to jump between communications, electronics, computer science domains. But it is usually not so for something like genetic engineering even though it is considered an interdisciplinary field. Institutions might expect graduation from either of biotechnology, molecular biology, microbiology or biochemistry.

This would however be different for fields such as genomics and bioinformatics where institutions *do* accept CS graduates *provided* they have a background in areas like data analytics, machine learning, data mining, data science and the like.

As this would depend on the eligibility and preference criteria of the institution concerned, it would be better for your to consult with the prospective institution that would offer the program desired.